# Unable to sort /search results by creation_date

Tags: bug, status-completed, api-v2, search

I think I may have stumbled upon a bug in [/search](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/search) and I'll try to describe it as best as I can.

**What works:**

- Create a `/search` query with the following parameters:

  - fromdate: 2012-01-24
  - order: desc
  - sort: creation
  - tagged: android

Alternatively, go to the following URL:

http://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/search?fromdate=1327363200&order=desc&sort=creation&tagged=android&site=stackoverflow

And you should see a bunch of Android related questions.

**What does not work:**

- Create a `/search` query with the following parameters:

  - fromdate: 2012-01-24
  - todate: 2012-01-30
  - order: desc
  - sort: creation
  - tagged: android

Note that I've added the `todate` field in this query. The related URL is:

http://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/search?fromdate=1327363200&todate=1327881600&order=desc&sort=creation&tagged=android&site=stackoverflow

The last query, for whatever reason, *does not* return any results (`"items": []`). Is this a bug in the system or have I horribly misinterpreted the query parameters :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fromdate` and `todate` were being applied in the wrong part of the pipe for [/search](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/search) and [/similar](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/similar).  This has been fixed.

Do be aware that `fromdate` and `todate` always apply to `creation_date`.  If you're looking to apply limits to other sorts, you need to use `min` and `max`.